# Ruby: Does Test::Unit still exist?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am following the codeschool course on testing with Ruby and they are using `Test::Unit`. When I try to `require test/unit` though it says the following:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  test.rb:1:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
/
```

When I follow the instructions and `require 'minitest/autorun'`, and then try to run my test it does not recognize the method assert_equal

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `assert_equal' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

So what is the deal with this? Does test/unit no longer exist? If that is the case, how do I run test with minitest? Does minitest use the same syntax or is it something different entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minitest is the new name for Test::Unit. It is fully compatible. Your syntax will still work for `assert_equal`,

You do need to put the code into a test case.'

Example:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestMe < Minitest::Test

   def test_foo  # test methods must begin with "test_"
     assert_equal 1, 1
   end

end
```

Comment: What is the name of the base class that my test class should inherent from?

Comment: `Minitest` is the new, new name.

Comment: @vgoff You're right; I'll adjust the capitalization now. Thanks!